# What is the Apple Developer API to access Apple AirTag data?

Tags: ios, swift, airtag

I am led to believe that developers can programmatically query their Apple AirTags for information such as location, direction distance away etc but can't find any samples, documentation or relevant API information to do this?

How can I access AirTag data or where can I find information that explains how to do this?

Comment: I am not aware of any APIs for any of Apple's "Find My" services, including Air Tags

Answer (score 3):

I can recommend you this discussion in the apple forum https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/678600

The API is requested since the AirTag release, but i did not notice any release on WWDC this year. So I dont think there is an API out there at the moment.

Maybe it will come next year (for sure it will one day, so many guys want that API ;))

Comment: Nearby API is used for AirTag: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/nearbyinteraction